# USB bootable of Chromium OS

Tags: usb, bootable-media, google-chrome-os

Anyone has a USB bootable of Chromium OS? When do you think it would be released? Does anyone have a review about it already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can [make one yourself:](http://www.daemonnews.org/2009/11/25/how-to-install-chrome-os-from-a-usb-drive.html)

- Get the OS image

Download the Hexxeh's Chromium OS build  ([torrent](http://bit.ly/8frVBr) | [http 1](http://bit.ly/7N9yxW) | [http 2](http://bit.ly/5O3nLV) ).

- Set Up Your USB Stick

Instructions for writing your Chromium OS image onto a USB stick for

- [Windows](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/windows.html)

> Download [Image Writer for Windows](http://bit.ly/7gRu0n)
>   and extract the
>   program. Launch the program, and
>   select the image (`ChromeOS-Cherry.img`)
>   and your USB drive letter from the
>   drop down box. Click "Write". The
>   install image will then be copied to
>   the drive. Once it's done, close the
>   program and you can then boot from the
>   USB drive.

- [Linux](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/linux.html)

> Extract ChromeOS-Cherry.img and run
>   the following command in the same
>   directory as the file, where X is the
>   device name of your USB drive.

```
sudo dd if=ChromeOS-Cherry.img of=/dev/X bs=4M
```

> Once the command finishes, you can
>   then boot from the USB drive.

- [Mac](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/mac.html).

> Firstly, unmount the drive you want to install Chromium OS to. Place
>   the downloaded file onto your desktop.
>   Open System Profiler, click USB on the
>   list at the side and then select the
>   entry that represents your USB disk.
>   Now look for the [BSD Name column](http://bit.ly/5mG4WK).
>   Remember what is written here. In my
>   case, it is disk1, but in yours it may
>   be different. Take care here as if you
>   get it wrong, it could seriously mess
>   things up. Once you have this, open up
>   Terminal and type the following
>   commands.

```
cd Desktop 
tar -zxvf ChromeOS-Cherry.tar.gz
```

> For the next command, replace X with
>   the name of the disk you found
>   earlier, ie disk1.

```
sudo dd if=ChromeOS-Cherry.img of=/dev/X bs=4m
```

> This command will ask you to enter
>   your password (the same one you enter
>   when installing software for example),
>   type it in and press enter. This
>   command will take a while to run,
>   about 20 minutes for me, and then will
>   give you your shell prompt back once
>   it has finished. Once it has, you can
>   remove your USB drive and boot from it
>   (but not on your Mac because I'll tell
>   you now that won't work, yes I tried
>   it)

And then, boot from USB!

NOTE: The username and password are both facepunch for this build.

Comment: I followed the instructions here : http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/wiki/doku.php?id=windows_instructions . now my usb drive is unreadable in windows. How do i format my pen drive

Comment: You should be able to format from within Windows, else boot using a Linux live CD & follow this post -> http://sathyasays.com/2007/06/13/formatting-usb-pen-drive-in-linux-using-terminal/

Answer (score 0):

Already [been done](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-google-chrome-os-and-run-on-a-real-computer/) my friend :)

In a nutshell:

- Grab the download off the above link, it includes everything you need
- Unzip the Chromium OS archive then use [Image Writer](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) to write `chrome_os.img` to your empty USB drive (back up everything on the USB first, it will be overwritten)
- Configure your computer to boot from USB
- Leave the drive plugged in while you boot and cross your fingers!

Remember, the OS is in the early stages of development, not all hardware will work 100%.