# Google Chrome OS on Acer Aspire One AOA 150 netbook

Tags: netbook, google-chrome-os, acer-aspire-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB bootable of Chromium OS](https://superuser.com/questions/89483/usb-bootable-of-chromium-os)

I have a Acer Aspire One AOA 150 with Windows Xp Home. I want to try and dual boot it with Google Chrome OS. But before that I would like to try it by booting from a USB? Where i can find instructions for doing so ? I also want to know user experiences of AOA 150 users after trying Google Chrome  out .

Comment: You can find full instructions for making a bootable ChromeOS USB stick here: http://superuser.com/questions/89483/usb-bootable-of-chromium-os/89494

Comment: No mention of this netbook's drivers in the other related thread .

Answer (score 0):

I built it myself from sources, using their instructions. Not too difficult, but a lot of steps.

You need to have the Atheros wireless, and not Broadcom. There's a sticker on the bottom of the case.

Unfortunately, it's not fast enough to play Hulu video without skipping, which plays fine with Windows. This is apparently a generic Flash-on-Linux issue; it didn't work with Ubuntu Netbook Remix either.

I appreciate what Google is trying to do. But when they finally release the official Chrome OS at the end of the year, I suppose the hardware will definitely be better, and offer a better overall experience. People will try to take the open source Chromium OS code and shoe-horn it into other boxes, but it will not be good enough.